# Android Syncronization - Data Already exist in Table

Tags: java, android, webserver, synchronization

I need some suggestions please. In my app there is login table, and I need to synchronize the login data (from the webserver) to my app. Everyday a new person add an account.

So now the table looks like this:

Login Table

```
 id    name      age
 1     David     23
 2     John      24
 3     Mathew    23
 4     James     25
```

Let's say tomorrow a new person named Paul is added; the app connects to the webserver to retrieve data and stores the data in the app login table.

If I got a new person, how can I store that person alone in the table without disturbing the old records?

**If the webserver showed only the newly added accounts, then this would be no problem at all for me, I could easily store the new account. Instead, the webserver is showing all of the old records too.**

Do I need to, daily, delete the Login Table and store all of the data as new data? Or is there some other way in which I can sync only the newly added data to my table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always write your own method, that determines whether the user is already in your local database or not.

All you need to do is store the webserver's result in some sort of an array (ie: ArrayList), read the existing users from you local database in another array, and check for differences. If there's a difference, you can simply insert the new user into your db.

Or if you don't want to deal with this, then simply empty the table and insertt he whole result into it.

Comment: there will be thousands of records so array checking and empty the Table will take more time..Is there any-other way...

Comment: Why don't you store the date of the registration in your remote db as well as in your local db? That way you can write a query that checks the the lastly added user's reg. date in your local DB and write a query that only shows those users - from your remote db - who were added after that specific date.